# Adding Multiple Markers From JSON By Using Timer

Tags: android, mysql, json, google-maps, timer

I'd read All Related Articles related to my question.. but I don't Have a complete answer...

Please Help Me Doing This App !!
My App : adding multiple markers with TIMER from JSON File that have been parsed from MySQL database:
this is THE JSON :

```
[
    {
        "id": "11",
        "sigma": "10",
        "gs": "10",
        "longtitude": "10",
        "latitude": "10",
        "altitude": "1000"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "sigma": "45",
        "gs": "FU",
        "longtitude": "40",
        "latitude": "40",
        "altitude": "977.0"
    }
]
```

and MY App Code :

```js
                    for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject sonJson = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         longtitude = sonJson.getDouble("longtitude");
                       latitude = sonJson.getDouble("latitude");
                        altitude=sonJson.getDouble("altitude");

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(longtitude, latitude);

                        arrayti.add(""+longtitude);
```

Comment: With timer ?what you mean by this?

Comment: where are you adding marker

Comment: I want  to know where to add marker-adding code

Comment: I want to make an arrayList of Type marker which stores markers with : longtitude and latitude data parsed from JSON

Comment: just want to put this all values in an arrayList?

Comment: i want to put these data in array list<Marker> and then pull them and add them in map..

Answer (score 0):

You have done things right.Instead of setting lat long in myLocation add them directly to map like this

```
LatLng home=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Workplace"));
```

Comment: I Need TO Parse Multiple Markers...this is my Problem

Comment: add all your markers from json to either arraylist or array whatever you like and then in run method loop through that arraylist/array and add marker with ith position from arraylist

Comment: Please help Me in Making This ArrayList

Comment: first create a bean class with fields latitude and longitude and in that bean class create a constructor that will take latitude and longitude as parameter

Comment: and then create an arraylist of bean type like this

ArrayList<HistoryBean> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: and then in run method add lat long to arraylist liket this
arraylist.add(new HistoryBean(latitude,longitude));

Comment: and after that loop through arraylist and add marker

Comment: thanks Sir ... But I didn't Understand how to place markers from arraylist.. ??

Comment: for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++
{
LatLng marker=new LatLng(arraylist.get(i).getLatitude,arraylist.get(i).getLongitude);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title("Workplace"));

replace getLatitude method with what you created in your bean class

Comment: Thanks My Friend For All That.. But Still Getting The First Value Of Database .. so I'm Getting only one Marker :(

Comment: Please Provide Me Your Email To send You the Complete Code.. I really appretiate your help.. I need To Add Multiple Markers

Comment: still doing wrong 
you are just adding a static marker on map and not from your list . You didn't followed completely what I told you

Comment: sorry .. but i didn't understand... please told me how to display multiple markers

Comment: and where is the arraylist??

Comment: My Friend ... I will Update my Code... I really need help

Comment: i want to store the markers in an arraylist ( longtitude, latitude ) ... then i would retrieve them on Handler.post() to add them to the map.... My Problem is Map is only displaying the first marker in database !

Comment: you are still doing wrong .First of all you are not adding your lat long properly in arraylist and second you are not displaying marker from arraylist .You are just adding a static marker on your map and that's why you are having only one marker.Read previous comment carefully and search for it accordingly if you didn' understand it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All especially Vivek Mishra.... It works Good but by this way!

```js
for (int i=0;i<arrayti.size();i++){

 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayti.get(i)).title("My Marker"));
                        }
```